# indexes and partition switching - how it works

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning

We use partition switches to quickly load data, switching entire tables.  We load an empty Table A with INSERTs and then switch it with empty Table B.  These tables have identical indexes.

What I don't understand why Table A's index as no fragmentation but Table B's index has fragmentation (16% in one example).  I assume because both tables had to have the same indexing, the indexes also got switched, but clearly that's not the case.

I am looking for an explanation as to how this works and why this happens.

Comment: Do you have an example script you can share? Or the code that you are using in order to determine the fragmentation %? My understanding is that [fragmentation is computed on a per-partition basis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx). When you are switching a partition from one table to another, the data within that partition is not touched and fragmentation of that partition therefore remains unchanged by definition.

Comment: I can update my question later tonight with an example script but it's a simple "alter table table_a switch to table_b" - and I was checking fragmentation in the SSMS object browswer...

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the indexes on table b and then switching to see what happens?

Comment: You'll likely need to refresh the display in SSMS prior to re-checking the fragmentation level.  In fact, don't use the GUI to check it, there could be land mines all over that.